# Facing an issue in registering Hive UDF in beeline

Tags: hive, hiveql, beeline

I was trying to register an HIVe UDF as detailed below but end up with errors. Please advise me what to do in this case?

0:

```
 jdbc:hive2://g4t7479.calfor.abbcorp.net:1> ADD JAR  /MAPR/DBLCLK/double_click/HiveUDF/AXX-DoubleClick-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
Error: Error while processing statement: /MAPR/DBLCLK/double_click/HiveUDF/AXX-DoubleClick-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar does not exist (state=,code=1)

0: jdbc:hive2://g4t7479.calfor.abbcorp.net:1> CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION stringTrim as 'com.axx.gma.dclick.StringTrim' USING JAR 'hdfs://MAPR/DBLCLK/double_click/HiveUDF/AXX-DoubleClick-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar';
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: MAPR (state=42000,code=40000)

0: jdbc:hive2://g4t7479.calfor.abbcorp.net:1> CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION stringTrim as 'com.axx.gma.dclick.StringTrim' USING JAR 'hdfs:://MAPR/DBLCLK/double_click/HiveUDF/AXX-DoubleClick-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar';
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: hdfs::/MAPR/DBLCLK/double_click/HiveUDF/AXX-DoubleClick-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Error while processing statement: /MAPR/DBLCLK/double_click/HiveUDF/AXX-DoubleClick-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar does not exist (state=,code=1)

above error message suggests that jar is not preset and has not been added so creating a function using that JAR will for sure give you error.

check if JAR exists using following command. This will work for hdfs if you using different file system command might be different.

> hdfs dfs -ls /MAPR/DBLCLK/double_click/HiveUDF/AXX-DoubleClick-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

if it's not you need to move file from your local system to your `hdfs` file system. or change the command to `ADD LOCAL JAR` (this does not work in beeline though)

Even if you don't get any error while adding a JAR it's a good idea to use following command (from hive or beeline) to make sure it has been added.

> list jars;

This will show you all the jars which has been added.